# TypeError: jsonErrors is not an object

Tags: ember.js

I recently upgraded to a canary build of Ember.js 1.0. After the upgrade, Ember can no longer parse validation errors from the server. I handle a form submit action like this:

```
submit: (event, view) ->
  @get('model').save().then ((response) =>
    @transitionToRoute('organization.timeline', @content)
  ), (response) =>
    @set "errors", response.responseText
```

Before updating to the canary build, this worked as expected. Now, I get this error when validation fails:

```
TypeError: jsonErrors is not an object
```

This happens during the call to `save`, so that even if I reduce the code to:

```
submit: (event, view) ->
  @get('model').save()
```

I still get the error.

I heard in a talk by Tom Dale that Ember is rolling out a new system for handling validation errors, and I'm assuming that's what's causing the conflict. I can't find any documentation (even a pull request) for this new approach. If anyone can point me in the right direction, it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I needed to change the way I was sending the error. I'm using a Rail backend. The response code looked like this:

```
def create
  organization = Organization::Master.find(params[:id])
  if organization.update_attributes(organization_params)
    render json: organization, status: 201
  else
    render json: organization.errors, status: 422
  end
end
```

Ember now supports a simpler approach:

```
def create
  organization = Organization::Master.find(params[:id])
  organization.update_attributes(organization_params)
  respond_with organization
end
```

With that, Ember is able to parse the errors.